# How to print the maximum consecutive occurrences of 1's in python 2.7?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, binary

The task is to take an integer input from the user, convert it into binary and print the maximum consecutive occurrences of 1's in the binary representation.

Here is my code:

```
import re
x = int(raw_input())
y = bin(x)[2:]
print "Binary of", x, "is =",y
count = 0
for i in re.findall('11', y):
    count =+ 1
print "Nb of consecutive 1's =",  count
```

I input 13 and here is the output I get:

```
Binary of 13 is = 1101
Nb os consecutive 1's = 1
```

I should be getting Nb of consecutive 1's = 2.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing at this time is finding all the times you have '11'.  try the binary of 15 and you will see what I'm saying

Comment: I dont know much about regex, but I'd imagine that what you are searching for is occurrences of `11` then there is only one in `1101`. You need a different regex.

Comment: When I do this for 15( binary = 1111) I still get Nb of consecutive 1's = 1

Comment: @suyashgautam you have =+ but should have +=.  Try that.  Its still not what you want, but that will get you what I stated in my comment

Comment: Oh I got it now. Good pick, thanks @RSon1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this :

```
get_num_ones = re.findall(r"1+", y)
print "Maximum Nb of consecutive 1's =", len(max(get_num_ones, key=len))
```

What I'm doing here is get all the possible consecutive one's in the binary string, and then I pick the string with longest length.

Comment: `sorted` (`O(n log n)`) to get a single value? Perhaps you want `max` (`O(n)`)?

Comment: @Jarvis Could you the explain the  "key = len" section in  `len(max(get_num_ones, key = len))`

Comment: The second parameter of `max` function is the parameter used for sorting, which is the length here (hence len), and I take the maximum of this.

Answer (score 2):

You could `split()` the string on zeros, and `max()` the resulting list of substrings made up only of '111':

```
#!python3

number = 32956415
bits = bin(number)[2:] # bits = '1111101101101111111111111'
                       #        '....5..2..2.............13'

print(bits)
runs_of_ones = bits.split('0')
longest_run = len(max(runs_of_ones, key=len))

print("Longest run is %d ones." % longest_run)
```

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory `groupby` functional one liner.

```
from itertools import groupby

print(max(map(lambda g: len(list(g[1])), filter(lambda a: a[0] == '1', groupby('1111101101101111111111111')))))
```

Use groupby to partition string into characters with same value, as it is not sorted there will be several groups for non-adjacent sets of the same characters. Then `filter` out any groups that are not groups of `1` and map the values to the length of the grouped chars, finally obtain the largest of those lengths using `max`.

Not all that readable in my opinion, but interesting nonetheless.

If broken up into several lines, it could be implemented as

```
maxlen = 0
# group
for grouper, group in groupby('1111101101101111111111111'):
    # filter
    if grouper == '1':
        # map
        thislen = len(list(group))
        # check max
        if thislen > maxlen:
            maxlen = thislen

print(maxlen)
```

Comment: I appreciate the new approach, it does seem interesting. Although I'd be honest, I am a beginner in Python and I am looking for something simpler, step by step, even if the code is large.

Comment: I added a broken down version thats easier to grok.